# Ruby on Rails - Randomizar variável JSON e aplicar em Array

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, random

Galera, estou com um problema que relativamente é simples, mas que está acabando comigo.

Tenho uma array de objetos JSON. Essa array de objetos irá compor uma outra array de contendo outras *n* arrays.

Até aí tudo bem. Porém, o que ocorre é que a cada iteração eu randomizo o atributo "valor" e coloco o objeto nessa nova array. E quando vou ver, no final das iterações, todos os objetos têm o mesmo valor (o do último random).

Alguém pode me ajudar?

[image: Código]
[image: Resultado]

Comment: Em vez de uma imagem poste o código directamente na pergunta.

Answer (score 1):

Acontece que você diz que é somente '=', tente adicionar com << e ver o que acontece.

```
times << $parametros[populacaoInicial''].to_i
```

> Ou então http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-push

```
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
arr.push(5) #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
arr << 6    #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```